# How to export PDF/CSV files using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, export-to-csv, export-to-pdf

Is there any way to create pdf/csv files using javascript which supports both desktop and device browsers? I have tried using **jsPDF**, but it has support only for desktop browsers and is not working on mobile browsers. Is there any libraries which have support on both desktop and mobile browsers?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you tried PDFjs?

Comment: @BikasVaibhav: It's also not working in mobile devices but working in desktop browsers.